# Again see the Welcome menu after installing FreeBSD on Virtualbox

Tags: virtual-machines, freebsd, virtualbox

I've installed Virtualbox 6.1 on my local computer with Windows 10. Next I've downloaded FreeBSD image and select it as virtual optical disk. Next I gone the FreeBSD installation process and restarted the system, but now I again see the Welcome menu with the options "Install", "Shell" and "Live CD".

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just need to delete optical disk after instllation.